Why does the Gelman plot of a JAGS model start at 1000?
I am looking at the diagnostics of a Bayesian model using rjags in R. In particular, I am considering its Gelman-Rubin-Brooks plot. Independent of the number of iterations and despite the fact that I am not using burn-in, the plot's x-axis begins at a number larger than 1000 and not at 0. What is the reason for this?
library(rjags)

data_list <- list(
  "nx" = 1, 
  "N" = 4
)

model_string <- "
  model {
    p ~ dbeta(1, 1)
    nx ~ dbinom(p, N)
}
"

model <- jags.model(
  file = textConnection(model_string),
  data = data_list,
  n.chains = 3
)

samples_small <- coda.samples(
  model = model,
  variable.names = "p",
  n.iter = 100
)
samples_big <- coda.samples(
  model = model,
  variable.names = "p",
  n.iter = 5000
)

gelman.plot(samples_small)
gelman.plot(samples_big)

Plot for samples_small:

Plot for samples_large:

PS: While this is code-related question, it is not really a programming problem. Hence, CrossValidated appears to be the forum of choice IMHO. Please kindly let me know if I should switch to SO.

Burnin, I presume

See here.

The reason for this behaviour is the default argument n.adapt = 1000 of the jags.model() function, i.e. we are actually calling:
model <- jags.model(
  file = textConnection(model_string),
  data = data_list,
  n.chains = 3,
  n.adapt = 1000
)

The reason for this is explained in the help for rjags::adapt(): When a JAGS model is compiled, it may require an initial sampling phase during which the samplers adapt their behaviour to maximize their efficiency (e.g. a Metropolis-Hastings random walk algorithm may change its step size). The sequence of samples generated during this adaptive phase is not a Markov chain, and therefore may not be used for posterior inference on the model.
In particular, this behaviour is not unique to gelman.plot() but occurs in other plots as well.
PS: Thank you to @PBulls for answering the question in a comment.
